# Coefficient of $x^{25}$

Tags: combinatorics

How would one go about finding the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(1+x^3 + x^8)^{10}$?

I've tried seeing if I can make the polynomial look like an identity, but I can't see to.

Comment: Hint: Figure out all the ways of writing $25$ as a sum of $3$s and $8$s. Then add the corresponding multinomial coefficients.

Comment: The above is also a suggestion about how you might add relevant amounts of context to your question. In SE the askers are expected to do a bit of (re)search before asking.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. By [expanding two binomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we have that
$$(1+x^3 + x^8)^{10}=(1+x^3(1 + x^5))^{10}=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}x^{3k}(1+x^5)^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{10}{k}\binom{k}{j}x^{3k+5j}.$$
Now note that $25=3\cdot 5+5\cdot 2$. Are there any other ways to write $25$ as $3k+5j$ with $0\leq j\leq k\leq 10$?
What is the coefficient of $x^{25}$?

Answer (score 2):

When multiplying out the product, the term $x^{25}$ will arise a number of times, depending on how many times one can write $25$ as a sum of $3$'s and $8$'s **where the order of summation matters**. It's clear that we need at least one $8$ to write $25$ like this, since $3$ doesn't divide $25$. For the same reason, we see that we actually need exactly two $8$'s, and then $(25-16)/3=3$ $3$'s. So how many ways are there of permuting the terms on the left hand side of $8 + 8 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 25$? Well, exactly ${5}\choose{2}$ $= 10$ ways since the order of the $8$'s and $3$'s is fixed once the $8$'s have been placed. But now, since there are $10$ factors of the polynomial $1 + x^3 + x^8$, we need to multiply $10$ by the number of ways of choosing $5$ factors out of the $10$ factors. So the result will be ${10}\choose{5}$$\cdot 10 = 2520$.

Comment: I really appreciate the response and has cleared a lot up actually, for me. I've followed everything you said, I think, up until the last part. Why do we need to choose 5 of the 10 factors?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. The reason why we need to choose 5 out of 10 factors is the following: We know that to write 25, we need exactly three 3's and two 8's, ie. in five of the ten factors, we have to choose a term different from 1, namely either x^3 or x^8. We can choose to take the three x^3 and two x^8 from the first five factors, but we could just as well take them from five other factors. Each possibility of choosing these five factors gives us 10 ways of positioning the 3's and 8's among each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.

Can you write $25$ as a sum of $8$'s and $3$'s?

Comment: We can say $3+3+3 + 8+8$

Comment: I think I'm missing something somewhat obvious.

Comment: Good, @Ryan. Any other ways?

Comment: @RyanGoulden Ok Ryan, so one can say that $25=2 \cdot 8 + 3\cdot3$. Can you now count words of length $10$ made from two 8's, three 3's combinatorically?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, thank you for destroying me :-)

Answer (score 1):

As for the binomial development, there is also the trinomial development.

$$(a+b+c)^n=\sum\limits_{i+j+k=n} \binom{n}{i,j,k}a^ib^jc^k$$

with $\displaystyle \binom{n}{i,j,k} =\dfrac{n!}{i!j!k!}$

In our case $a=1$, $b=x^3$ and $c=x^8$, thus

$$(1+x^3+x^8)^{10}=\sum\limits_{i+j+k=10} \binom{10}{i,j,k}1^ix^{3j}x^{8k}=\sum\limits_{i+j+k=10} \binom{10}{i,j,k}x^{3j+8k}$$

We want the coefficient of $x^{25}$ so we need $3j+8k=25\iff j=3,k=2$ and this forces $i=5$.

The coefficient is then $\displaystyle\binom{10}{5,3,2}=\dfrac{10!}{5!3!2!}=\dfrac{10.9.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1}{(5.4.3.2.1).(3.2.1).(2.1)}=5.9.8.7=2520$