# Find a coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(x + x^{2} +x^{3} +x^{4})^{5}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find a coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $$(x + x^{2} +x^{3} +x^{4})^{5}$$

Using formula for the sum of a geometric series I have turned it into $$x^5(1-x^4)(1-x)^{-4} $$

So now I see that in $(1-x^4)(1-x)^{-4}$ we need to find coefficient of $x^7$ as we actually have $x^5$, am I right?

If so I unfortunately still don't know what I should do as my next step to calculate this coefficient.

Comment: This is very similar to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809223/find-a-coefficient-of-x12-in-1x3-x6-x9-7).

Comment: It's the coefficient of $x^7$ in $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5=\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^5$$

Comment: Do you know the coefficients of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^5}$?

Comment: In how many ways can you write 12 as a sum of five numbers, each from 1 to 4?

Comment: You can use the method in this analogous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/989889/177399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the same as the number of integral solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=12$ where $1\le x_i\le 4$ for all i.

There is a one-to-one bijection between solutions to this diophantine equation and $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5 = 7$ where $0\le y_i \le 3$. There are $\dbinom{11}{4}$ integral solutions with no upper bounds. There are $\dbinom{7}{4}$ solutions that violate each bound. So, the coefficient of $x^{12}$ from your problem is $\dbinom{11}{4}-5\dbinom{7}{4} = 155$

Comment: I don't get at that moment why we subtract $5\dbinom{7}{4}$

Comment: Because you are looking for solutions where $\forall i: 0\le y_i \le 3$ and there are $\dbinom{11}{4}$ solutions where $\forall i: 0\le y_i$ (no upper bound). So, we need to subtract solutions that violate the upper bound. That means that for a single $i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, we have $4\le y_i$. Let's consider when $4\le y_1$ and $\forall i\neq 1: 0\le y_i$. The solutions of this equation are in bijection with the solutions of $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5 = 3$ where $\forall i: 0\le z_i$. There are $\dbinom{7}{4}$ integral solutions to this equation...

Comment: Each solution to the equation for $z_i$'s corresponds to a solution in $y_i$'s where the upper bound for $y_1$ is violated. Next, we find the solutions where $y_2$ is violated to be the same number. Similarly for $y_3, y_4, y_5$. By Inclusion/Exclusion, we need to check the number of solutions where exactly two variables upper bound is violated and add them back. Then subtract when 3 upper bounds are violated, add when 4 upper bounds are violated, and finally subtract when all 5 upper bounds are violated. Fortunately, there are zero solutions for when 2 or more upper bounds are violated.

Answer (score 3):

you can have a look at this post too : [Coefficient of $x^{25}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760114/coefficient-of-x25/2760145#2760145)

$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^5=\sum\limits_{i+j+k+l=5} \binom{5}{i,j,k,l}x^{i+2j+3k+4l}$$

The coefficient $x^{12}$ is obtained when $i+2j+3k+4l=12$.

$\begin{array}{cccc|c}
i & j & k & l & \dfrac {5!}{i!j!k!l!}\\\hline
0 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 10\\
0 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 20\\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 60\\
2 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 30\\
2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 30\\\hline
&&&&155\end{array}$

Answer (score 2):

It is the coefficient of $x^7$ in:

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5=\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^5$$

The first two terms of the numerator are $(1-x^4)^5=1-5x^{4}+\dots$ with the other terms of degree $8$ or more, so we can ignore them. Now, if $\frac{1}{(1-x)^5}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ then the coefficient we are looking for is the coefficient of $x^7$ in:

$$(1-5x^4)\sum a_nx^n$$

Which is $a_7-5a_3.$

Ao do you know the sequence $\{a_n\}$?

---

This can also be written as an inclusion-exclusion result. Let $A$ be the set of all  integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=7$. Let $A_i$ be the subset of all such solutions with $x_i\geq 4.$

Note that $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$, and all the $A_i$ are the same size, so you get:

$$|A|-5|A_1|.$$

That looks similar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Determine the cardinality of $I=\{ i \in \{1,2,3,4\}^5 | i_1 +i_2 +i_3 +i_4 +i_5= 12\}$.

Stars & bars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one_2) gives 5 bins with 12 objects, hence $\binom{12-1}{5-1}$.

The problem with the stars & bars approach is that $i \in \mathbb{N}^5$
rather than $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}^5$. We need to remove the 'large' $i$s.

This is straightforward to address once we notice that in any 'large' $i$,
at most one $i_k \in \{5,...,8\}$.

If we pick $m \in \{5,...,8\}$, then number of 'large' $i$s with some $i_k = m$ is
$5 |\{ j \in \mathbb{N}^4 | i_1 +i_2 +i_3 +i_4 = 12-m \}|$, hence using
stars & bars again, we see that the number of large $i$s is
$5 \sum_{m=5}^8 \binom{11-m}{3}$, which we can compute using the
hockey stick identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) as $5 \binom{7}{4}$.

Hence we obtain the result
$\binom{11}{4}-5\binom{7}{4}$.

Comment: I like this one because there is no sum involved, it gives the binomial coefficient directly. Note: the coefficient is half the stars and bars.

Comment: @zwim Unfortunately I have a mistake, but it is hard to fic

Comment: Fix on the phone.

Comment: So is it $\binom{12-1}{5-1}$ or $\binom{12-1}{5-1}$ - $5*\binom{7}{4}$ as @InterstellarProbe wrote above? Coz I am a bit confused now

Comment: As I wrote above, I have a mistake which I have not had time to fix and I can't delete my answer from the phone.

Comment: @JamesSmith: I have fixed the result, which shows a marginally different approach to pruning the 'large' indices.

Comment: @zwim: Unfortunately I had a mistake, and ended up needing a sum (hockey stick) at the end...